# Why does printf display only the first letter?

Tags: c, unicode, printf

First of all, I have a function where I have signs stored in `unsigned char*` type. For example for `Abcdef!?` it is `[65 0] [98 0] [99 0] [100 0] [101 0] [102 0] [33 0] [63 0]` 2 bytes per sign in Unicode.

When I use `for(unsigned char i=0; i<17; i++) printf("%c", pointer[i]);` everything is ok, it shows `Abcdef!?`. But when I use `printf("%s" pointer);` it gives me only `A` and nothing else. Could you tell me why?

Comment: second value is 0, it's a `unsigned char*` array type: `printf` stops. Can you show us a [mcve] please?

Comment: See all those `0` bytes? `%s` is for printing a c-string, which is null-terminated; it is properly called a *Null Terminated Byte String*. So you only get the first character before the first `0` byte, then it stops trying to read any more.

Comment: When you say “Unicode system” you mean UTF-16 or something similar, right? Unicode itself isn’t an encoding, it‘s just a mapping of characters to numbers.

Comment: UTF-16 is a variable-width encoding: Some characters take 2 bytes to encode, some take 4.

Comment: @melpomene Sure, nobody disputes that.

Comment: @Slava : The question applies just as much to C++ as to C.

Comment: @MartinBonner in C++ unicode should not be stored in `unsigned char *` and should not be sent to output by `printf()`

Comment: @Slava Much as people may think `printf` is not C++ish, it's as much a part of the standard as iostreams - and I can't see any difference in the desirability of storing unicode in `unsigned char *` between C and C++.

Comment: @MartinBonner *Even if* the answer happens to be the same for C and C++ in this particular case, this is far from obvious in general. There are enough questions on SO that are tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] for which the answer differs. It makes sense to limit and focus questions on one language only.

Comment: Thank you. Your answers gave me hint and I managed to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `printf("%s", pointer)` literally means: *Print every `char` starting at the one stored at `pointer` until `'\0'` is encountered.*

There's a `'\0'` immediately after `'A'`, so only the first character is printed.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Maybe.  That will work on Windows (where `wchar_t` stores UTF-16).  It won't work on Linux platforms which tend to a four byte `wchar_t` storing UCS4 (and this is not UCS4).

Comment: @FiddlingBits: No. `%ls` takes a pointer to `wchar_t` not a pointer to `char`. Even if `wchar_t` is 16-bit little endian (broken MSVC definition, incompatible with Unicode) it's an aliasing violation to access the `char` array as `wchar_t` and might fail alignment requirement too.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: I suppose that would be formally UB, because `%ls` is for `wchar_t*`. However, the C++ tag was removed from the question, and I'm not 100% sure about these things in C.